# Giving a unique numeric id for a name

Tags: php, string, md5

I have the following code on my index.php file

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$id = rand(0,100); // i need a unique id from the name than random
?>
```

What i want to do is, when someone supply their name, a unique numeric id between 0 and 100 should be shown. It should not be changed after refreshing the page.

For example,
if user supply the name "John" , id should be "99" (or any other number which will not change)
if user supply the name "david" , id should be "5" (or any other number which will not change)

I tried using md5 but it generates more numbers and i couldn't use it well as i'm a newbie in php.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: So what's wrong with this code? That should give you the random number. You are having issues with the refresh or what? `md5` isn't random it will generate the same value for every name (and could have the same value for different names (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value)).

Comment: What's wrong with having more than 2-3 digits?

Answer (score 0):

rand() function only gives you random number but it never gives you unique number for any word. The best solution is using md5 which converts your name to hash of
string which is always unique. If you need help with md5 , then do let me know.

Comment: I need to generate an md5 hash which contains numbers only ( between 0 to 100). There must be chances to get all the 100 numbers for every name.

Comment: md5 can not generate number between 0 to 100 and if you use rand() then the number will not be unique to each name.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of number in a array, then we shuffle it. Get elements of shuffled array.

```
function generateRandomNumberInRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
     $randomNumberArray = range($min, $max);
     shuffle($randomNumberArray);
     return array_slice($randomNumberArray, 0, $quantity);
}

echo "<pre>";
$numbersArray = generateRandomNumberInRange(0, 100, 101);
print_r($numbersArray);
echo "</pre>"

for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo $numbersArray[$i] . "<br/>";
}
```

Then you assign name to unique and random number.